# How can I make the social icons align to the center on mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a footer which looks fine on desktop.

[image]

On mobile, I would like the social icons to be centered as well just like the text above it.

[image]

This is the code:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen-readers {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.footer {
  background: #921801;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-col-1 p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.footer-col-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.social li + li {
  margin-left: 0.8em;
}

.social li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3eb3c88b5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer-social.css">
  <title>Footer Social</title>
</head>
<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">

      <div class="footer-col-1">
        <p>Copyright 2021 My Name. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-col-2">
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Facebook">
              <i class="icon-facebook fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Facebook</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="YouTube">
              <i class="icon-youtube fab fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true" title="YouTube"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">YouTube</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Likedin">
              <i class="icon-linkedin fab fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true" title="Linkedin"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Linkedin</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Vimeo">
              <i class="icon-vimeo fab fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Vimeo"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Vimeo</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Twitter">
              <i class="icon-twitter fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Twitter"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Twitter</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="IMDB">
              <i class="icon-imdb fab fa-imdb" aria-hidden="true" title="IMDB"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">IMDB</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- / .footer-col-2 -->
    </div> <!-- / .footer-container -->
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I can fix it by using a `flex-direction: column` for mobile and `align-items: center` Am I right? Then on the desktop use the `flex-direction: row` but that requires media queries which now I don't have.

Is there a different way to fix it? What I want is the social icons to be centered as well on mobile after they wrap, but the desktop to stay the same as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-content: center` to `.social`, which is the flex container that contains the social media icons, and  `width: 100%;` to `.footer-col-2`

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen-readers {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.footer {
  background: #921801;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-col-1 p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.footer-col-2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

.social li + li {
  margin-left: 0.8em;
}

.social li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3eb3c88b5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer-social.css">
  <title>Footer Social</title>
</head>
<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">

      <div class="footer-col-1">
        <p>Copyright 2021 My Name. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-col-2">
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Facebook">
              <i class="icon-facebook fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Facebook</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="YouTube">
              <i class="icon-youtube fab fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true" title="YouTube"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">YouTube</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Likedin">
              <i class="icon-linkedin fab fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true" title="Linkedin"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Linkedin</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Vimeo">
              <i class="icon-vimeo fab fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Vimeo"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Vimeo</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Twitter">
              <i class="icon-twitter fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Twitter"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Twitter</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="IMDB">
              <i class="icon-imdb fab fa-imdb" aria-hidden="true" title="IMDB"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">IMDB</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- / .footer-col-2 -->
    </div> <!-- / .footer-container -->
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your time. The problem is that it messes up the desktop look, which I want to stay the same as in the image above. In other words I want the icons to the right on the desktop and on center on mobile.

Comment: Well, of course you should put those settings into a media query (`@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { ... mobile rules here ... }`) - or whatever max-width you want to use for it.

Comment: then it wouldn't better to make the flex direction column on mobile and row on desktop? Once the direction is column I can align with `align-items: center`

Answer (score 0):

Add this following code to your CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 690px) {
      .footer-col-2 {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
}
```

You can change the max-width if you want but at the end it should look like this (**Run code snippet**) :

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen-readers {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.footer {
  background: #921801;
}

.footer-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-col-1 p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.footer-col-2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.social li + li {
  margin-left: 0.8em;
}

.social li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add this: */

@media only screen and (max-width: 690px) {
  .footer-col-2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3eb3c88b5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="footer-social.css">
  <title>Footer Social</title>
</head>
<body>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-container">

      <div class="footer-col-1">
        <p>Copyright 2021 My Name. All Rights Reserved.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-col-2">
        <ul class="social">
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Facebook">
              <i class="icon-facebook fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Facebook</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="YouTube">
              <i class="icon-youtube fab fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true" title="YouTube"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">YouTube</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Likedin">
              <i class="icon-linkedin fab fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true" title="Linkedin"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Linkedin</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Vimeo">
              <i class="icon-vimeo fab fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Vimeo"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Vimeo</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Twitter">
              <i class="icon-twitter fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true" title="Twitter"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">Twitter</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="IMDB">
              <i class="icon-imdb fab fa-imdb" aria-hidden="true" title="IMDB"></i>
              <span class="screen-readers">IMDB</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- / .footer-col-2 -->
    </div> <!-- / .footer-container -->
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```